# How to use System.arraycopy in for loop

Tags: java, android

I have ArrayList of bytes.I want to use System.arraycopy function for combile all bytes of the ArrayList.Following is my code.

```
public void createFile(ArrayList<byte[]> arrayList) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Constant.MERGE_DIRECOTRY + "out" + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION.toString());
    for(byte[] data: arrayList)
        fos.write(data);

    fos.close();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MergerActivity.this, Uri.parse(Constant.MERGE_DIRECOTRY + "out" + Constant.FILE_EXTENSION.toString()));
    if(mp != null)
    {
        totalduration = totalduration + mp.getDuration();
        Log.d("duration",""+Utilis.milliSecondsToTimer(totalduration));
    }
}
```

How can i use  System.arraycopy function instead if fos.write().

Comment: Where should that copy too? Please give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `System.arraycopy` you have to first find out the required length of the output array:

```
int len = 0;
for(byte[] data: arrayList)
    len += data.length;
```

Now you can copy the source arrays to a target array:

```
byte[] output = new byte[len];
int pos = 0;
for(byte[] data: arrayList) {
    System.arrayscopy(data,0,output,pos,data.length);
    pos+=data.length;
}
```